# Retrieve Image from File Path and Encode it to Base64

Tags: javascript, cordova

I need to convert Base64 from provided image file path. Following are conversion codes:

```
var encodeImageUri = function(imageUri, callback) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        c.width = this.width;
        c.height = this.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            callback(dataURL);
        }
    };
    img.src = imageUri;
}

function getFileContentAsBase64(path,callback){
    console.log(path);

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, gotFile, fail);

    function fail(e) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    }

    function gotFile(fileEntry) {
       fileEntry.file(function(file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function(e) {
               var content = this.result;
               callback(content);
          };
          // The most important point, use the readAsDatURL Method from the file plugin
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       });
    }
}
```

How I use it:

```
var image = 'file://' + path;
getFileContentAsBase64(image, function (base64File) {});
encodeImageUri(image, function(base64){});
```

`path` example:

> file:///storage/emulated/0/test.jpeg

If I print base64 result to [Code Beautifier](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter#), one is corrupted with 3kb size only, and other 1 is error with broken image icon.

Comment: Where in your post is the sample base64 string you are retrieving?